# Ajustar tamanho de imagem com ImageIO Java

Tags: java, swing

Gostaria de redimensionar uma imagem para ser mostrada em minha jLabel. Aqui está meu código:

```
    BufferedImage imagem;
    Icon novaImg;
    try {
        String newPath = "file:///" + aleat(); // carrega imagem aleatória

        imagem = ImageIO.read(new URL(newPath));

        novaImg = new ImageIcon(imagem);
        jLabelPrincipal.setIcon(novaImg);
    } catch(IOException exception) {
        System.err.println(exception);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    BufferedImage imagem;
    Icon novaImg;
    try {
        String caminho = "file:///" + aleat(); // carrega imagem aleatória
        int largura = 200, altura = 300;
        imagem = ImageIO.read(new URL(caminho));
        novaImg = new ImageIcon(imagem.getScaledInstance(largura, altura,
        java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));

    } catch(IOException exception) {
        System.err.println(exception);
    }
```

Comment: imagem = (BufferedImage) imagem.getScaledInstance(largura, altura, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage

Comment: @user5693, editei a resposta e agora esta' sem o casting.

Comment: Essa nova ficou muito bom, exatamente do jeito que eu desejava! Obrigado!